# Splitting a python string

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a string in python that I want to split in a very particular manner. I want to split it into a list containing each separate word, except for the case when a group of words are bordered by a particular character. For example, the following strings would be split as such.

```
'Jimmy threw his ball through the window.'
```

becomes

```
['Jimmy', 'threw', 'his', 'ball', 'through', 'the', 'window.']
```

However, with a border character I'd want

```
'Jimmy |threw his ball| through the window.'
```

to become

```
['Jimmy', 'threw his ball', 'through', 'the', 'window.']
```

As an additional component I need `-` which may appear outside the grouping phrase to appear inside it after splitting up i.e.,

```
'Jimmy |threw his| ball -|through the| window.'
```

would become

```
['Jimmy', 'threw his', 'ball', '-through the', 'window.']
```

I cannot find a simple, pythonic way to do this without a lot of complicated for loops and if statements. Is there a simple way to handle something like this?

Comment: Why would there be? This seems very specific - have you looked into dedicated parsers?

Comment: Well there are nice pythonic ways do do the first part. I can do `' '.join(string.strip().split()).split()` to accomplish the first part, and I can do separately `str1.strip().split('|')` to turn `'Jeffery |threw a ball| at the boat.'` into `['Jeffery ', 'threw a ball', ' at the boat.']`.

Comment: Make a function: if the sentinal character is not in the string use ```str.split``` otherwise use ```re.split```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't something with an out-of-the-box solution, but here's a function that's pretty Pythonic that should handle pretty much anything you throw at it.

```
def extract_groups(s):
    separator = re.compile("(-?\|[\w ]+\|)")
    components = separator.split(s)
    groups = []
    for component in components:
        component = component.strip()
        if len(component) == 0:
            continue
        elif component[0] in ['-', '|']:
            groups.append(component.replace('|', ''))
        else:
            groups.extend(component.split(' '))

    return groups
```

Using your examples:

```
>>> extract_groups('Jimmy threw his ball through the window.')
['Jimmy', 'threw', 'his', 'ball', 'through', 'the', 'window.']
>>> extract_groups('Jimmy |threw his ball| through the window.')
['Jimmy', 'threw his ball', 'through the', 'window.']
>>> extract_groups('Jimmy |threw his| ball -|through the| window.')
['Jimmy', 'threw his', 'ball', '-through the', 'window.']
```

Comment: Thanks I used this solution with a few small modifications! I really should learn regex.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably some regular expression solving your problem. You might get the idea from the following example:

```py
import re
s = 'Jimmy -|threw his| ball |through the| window.'
r = re.findall('-?\|.+?\||[\w\.]+', s)
print r
print [i.replace('|', '') for i in r]
```

Output:

```
['Jimmy', '-|threw his|', 'ball', '|through the|', 'window.']
['Jimmy', '-threw his', 'ball', 'through the', 'window.']
```

Explanation:

- `-?` optional minus sign
- `\|.+?\|` pipes with at least one character in between
- `|` or
- `[\w\.]+` at least one "word" character or `.`

In case `,` or `'` can appear in the original string, the expression needs some fine tuning.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse that format using a regex, although your choice of delimiter makes it rather an ugly one!

This code finds all sequences that consist *either* of a pair of pipe characters `|` enclosing zero or more non-pipe characters, *or* one or more characters that are neither pipes nor whitespace.

```
import re

str = 'Jimmy |threw his| ball -|through the| window.'

for seq in re.finditer(r' \| [^|]* \| | [^|\s]+ ', str, flags=re.X):
    print(seq.group())
```

**output**

```
Jimmy
|threw his|
ball
-
|through the|
window.
```