# How can I create a bag of words for latex strings?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-mining, feature-extraction

I have a set of input paragraphs in latex formats. I want to create a bag of words from them.

Taking a set of guys that look like these:

```
"Some guy did something with \emph{ yikes } $ \epsilon $"
```

I want to out put a dictionary:

```
{ 
  "Some": 40,
   ...
   "yikes": 10
   "epsilon (or unicode for it)": 3
}
```

That is I need a dictionary where the set of keys are the set of words/symbols/equations (I'll call all of these words for brevity) across all paragraphs and a count of their occurrences across all paragraphs as well.

From there given k-ordered-tuple of words, I need a k-array for each paragraph where the ith element in the array represents the count of the word in the ith tuple in that paragraph.

so say `(Some, dunk, yikes, epsilon)` will give me 
`[1, 0, 1, 1]` for the stated example.

I've tried this by using a lexer to get the tokens out and processing the tokens directly. This is difficult and error prone not to mention slow. Is there a better strategy or tool that can do this?

There are some corner cases to consider with special characters:

```
G\""odel => Gödel
```

for example. I'd like to preserve these.

Also, I'd like to drop equations all together or keep them as one word. Equations occur in between $ ... $ signs.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean with "vectorize"? Can you give an example - input and desired output?

Comment: Hi Falko, I think this wiki article gives a good example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model#Example_implementation. Except the input is in latex in my case

Comment: I know the computer vision concept of bag-of-words. But just from the terms "vectorize" and "bag-of-words" it's impossible to infer what your actual objective is. I guess you want to build up the dictionary? - To attract someone to help you out you should give a clear minimum example of what you have and what you want.

Comment: Allright thankyou, I'll alter it to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to do the following:

1. Split the sentence into words:

   ```py
   s = "Some guy did something with \emph{ yikes } \epsilon"
   words = s.split()
   print words
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   ['Some', 'guy', 'did', 'something', 'with', '\\emph{', 'yikes', '}', '\\epsilon']
   ```
2. Count the number of occurrences:

   ```py
   from collections import Counter
   dictionary = Counter(words)
   print dictionary
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   Counter({'did': 1, '}': 1, '\\epsilon': 1, 'Some': 1, 'yikes': 1, 'something': 1, 'guy': 1, 'with': 1, '\\emph{': 1})
   ```
3. Access words and their corresponding numbers as separate lists:

   ```py
   print dictionary.keys()
   print dictionary.values()
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   ['did', '}', '\\epsilon', 'Some', 'yikes', 'something', 'guy', 'with', '\\emph{']
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
   ```

Note that I didn't process any word, yet. You might want to strip brackets or backslashes. But this can be easily done by traversing the dictionary (or lists) with a for-loop and handling each entry individually.

---

**To convert LaTeX umlauts** to unicode characters is somehow a whole new problem. There are several stackoverflow questions and answers on this topic. Maybe you just need to find/replace them in the initial string:

```py
s = s.replace('\\"o', unichr(252))
```

(Note that depending on your command line encoding you might not see umlauts with `print s`. But they are not lost, as can be shown using `print repr(s)`.)

**To preserve equations** you can split the string using a regular expression rather than `split`:

```
import re
print re.findall('\$.+\$|[\w]+', s)
```

Output:

```
['Some', 'guy', 'did', 'something', 'with', 'emph', 'yikes', '$ \\epsilon $']
```

Please see [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25828094/3419103) for a similar example and a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I tried something like this but I was loosing information. For example if a word is using the umlaut such as G\""odel (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96) the word is lost. Also I would like to preserve equations or drop them all together if possible. Equations occur between dollars $ .... $. Any recommendations? I'll change the question to reflect these cases as well.

Comment: @ArtisanV: I extended my answer to address these two issues. This should suffice to get it working in principle. I assume you'll find answers to more detailed issues on other stackoverflow discussions.